# Keyword extraction для русского языка

Tags: python, node.js, keyword, nlp, data-mining

***Задача:***

Есть некий текст(или html). Из него нужно получить набор ключевых слов (keywords).

***Проблема:***

В сети есть множество решений даной задачи, предназначенных для *английского* языка.Например:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/schenkerian (для node.js)
2. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-rake (для python)

Есть ли готовые решения этой задачи для *русского* языка?

Answer (score 0):

Появилась такая библиотека как multi-rake:
https://pypi.org/project/multi-rake/

Судя по описанию она подходит для любого языка.